# Como faço um evento quando clicar em um Item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, selecteditem

Queria saber se tem como, ao clicar em um item, realizar um evento/função, sabendo que cada item, tem sua função.

**Estou usando LongListSelector**

`Código XAML`

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="lstConsPais"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    LayoutMode="List" 
    IsGroupingEnabled="False"
    Width="456">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#111" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Height="100" Width="100"  Source="{Binding NomeImgBandeira}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomePais}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,25,0,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**Obs: A lista está sendo populada a partir de um arquivo XML, e eu queria pegar o nome do pais**

Se sim, poderia dar exemplos? Estou usando `WP C#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No [LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector) tem um evento [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) que fica responsável quando algum item for selecionado.

*Exemplo de código:*

```
private void LongListSelector1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem != null)
     {
         object cons = ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem;
         MessageBox.Show(cons.ToString());
     }
}
```

Obs: ***(((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem)***, ele pode aqui retornar um objeto, um tipo, etc, então, de um break point e verifique o que o mesmo está retornando

***Referência***:

- [Highlight a selected item in the LongListSelector on WP8](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444)
- [LongListSelector Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector_methods%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [LongListSelector Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector_events%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)